# Should we commment on spam to get it deleted faster?

Tags: discussion, comments, flagging, spam-handling

Recently I observe that obvious spam often gets far more down votes than spam flags would be needed for community deleting and locking:

[image]

Should we in case of an obvious spam post leave a comment so that users who don't know about the power of spam-flags will not downvote (this will remove the post from the front page and makes it harder to spot)  **but spam-flag** appropriately to get the spam deleted more quickly?

Here is the relevant MSO link on spam flags:

- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work)

Comment: I saw this spam on Skeptics.SE, but the user who posted it didn't have any accounts on other Stack Exchanges ... or so I thought.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Users often create separate accounts, sometimes even with the same display name.

Comment: Do not downvote spam questions! Flag as spam and nothing else. If you downvote spam questions, they drop off the front page once they reach a score of -4, which reduces the chance that they'll quickly get the 6 spam votes needed to delete them.

Comment: @Gilles: ty - good point. I edited the Q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never thought about that but yes - it would be wonderful if you did!